# Definitions of a core and proving that the interior/core of a convex set is also convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

The definition given in the book is that for a subset $A$ of a linear space $X$, $a \in \operatorname{cor}(A)$ if $\forall b \in X \setminus \{a\}, \exists x \in (a, b)$ such that $[a, x] \subset A$. I wanted to prove that the algebraic interior (core) of a convex set is also convex. The definition seemed super confusing and indirect at first but then I visualized it and it seemed equivalent to saying that there exists a ball centered at a that is entirely contained in $A$. Is that correct?

Furthermore, I am supposed to prove that if the convex set is also balanced, then its core is also balanced. The proof is apparently "very easy" but not simple enough for me, it seems.

Comment: What is $b$ in the definition?

Comment: I think that there was a typo in the question. I have fixed it, such that the definition matches the usual definition of "core".

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was supposed to be ∀ b ∈ X - {a}

Answer (score 1):

For the set
$$
A := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x \le 0 \text{ or } y \le \sqrt{|x|}\}$$
we have $0 \in \operatorname{core}(A)$, but no ball centered at $a$ is a subset of $A$.

[However, if $A$ is additionally convex, one very often have $\operatorname{core}(A) = \operatorname{interior}(A)$, e.g., if $X$ is finite-dimensional or if ($X$ is a Banach space and $A$ is closed)].